# Asp.Net MVC parameter is null when pass it from client side to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

**Javascript**
I have a method as follows,

```
        function OpenRecord(id ,module ,screen) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("OpenRecord", "Management", new { id = "_id", module = "_module",screen = "_screen" })';
            url = url.replace("_id", encodeURIComponent(id));
            url = url.replace("_module", encodeURIComponent(module));
            url = url.replace("_screen", encodeURIComponent(screen));
            window.location.href = url;
        }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult OpenRecord(string id, string module, string screen)
    {
        Int64 someID = Convert.ToInt64(id);


        /*some act**/

        return RedirectToAction(screen, module, new { id = someId});


    }
```

When I run this i get *id* and *module* but **screen** param is passed **null**. When i inspect client side on chrome dev tools, i see all the parameters on javascript method are filled and the final url in url variable as follows;

```
/Management/OpenRecord/112?module=Customer&amp;screen=MUSTRTANML
```

I guess that amp&; entity spoils my controller to get the last param but i am not sure and i don't know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `var url = '@Url.Action("OpenRecord", "Management")' + '/' + id + '?module=' + module + '&screen=' + screen;` (and you may as well make the parameter `long id` so its bound correctly)

Comment: That worked thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your `Url.Action` in `Html.Raw()`. Or you can go with replacement approach further - `url = url.replace("&amp;", "&")`. Whatever you like, personally I would proceed with `Html.Raw`

Answer (score 0):

you need to construct your url string with values

```
var url = '@Url.Action("OpenRecord", "Management", new { id = "_id", module = "_module",screen = "_screen" })';
```

this is wrong, it should be

```
var url = '/Management/OpenRecord?id=' + _id + '&module='+ _module + '&screen='+ _screen;
```

the above  will pass the values of the variables rather than names , you cannot execute Url.Action as part of JavaScript this is Razor code

Comment: those are not variables, just sign for replacement of the variables, below that line i make replacement.

Comment: still  window.location.href  don't understand what Url.Action is , you will have to construct the url manually